# Subtracting sum of amount from a table with sum of amount from another table

Tags: java, sql

I got wrong sql result that has double minus value for amount.

I want to subtract Sum of amount from a table with Sum of amount from another table.

This is `bet_tbl`(First Table) data. Check only `bet_Number` "11". Sum of amount for bet_tbl is 2000. See below.

`bet_tbl`:

[image]

This is `recover_tbl`(Second Table) data. Sum of amount for `recover_tbl` is 100.

See below.

[image]

Final result I want to get sum of amount after subtracting `bet_tbl.Amount` with `recover_tbl.Amount` is 1900.But I got 1800 when I ran the following query.See below.

```
select 
  `bet_Number`, 
  SUM(bet_tbl.`Amount`) - SUM(recover_tbl.`Amount`) AS 'AMOUNT'
from bet_tbl, recover_tbl
WHERE bet_tbl.status= recover_tbl.status
  AND bet_tbl.`bet_Date`=recover_tbl.`recover_Date` 
  AND bet_tbl.status = '0'
  AND bet_tbl.`bet_Date`='2013-07-02'
GROUP BY bet_tbl.`bet_Number`
```

The following is the result after running the query.

[Result]:

[image]

I can't find where I got wrong.I'm stuck in this and need a help.Thank for any suggestions and answers.

Comment: can't see your table or your result

Comment: Sorry about that kevinm.My uploaded pic was failed while I'm posting this question

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it will yield it 1800. This is because aggregation is performed after joining. 
You know there are two records with 11 bet_number with 1000 amount. Thus joining with another table will make two records...

```
bet_number           bet_tbl.Amount            recover_tbl.Amount
11                   1000                      100
11                   1000                      100
```

Now aggregating it would yeild

```
bet_number           SUM(bet_tbl.Amount)       SUM(recover_tbl.Amount)
11                   2000                      200
```

And thus the result is 2000 - 200 = 1800

You need to make aggregation in table bet_tbl before subtracting the amounts with recover_tbl. Something like

```
SELECT 
T1.*
FROM
(
    select 
    bet_number,
    SUM(Amount) Amount
    FROM
    bet_tbl
    WHERE 
    bet_tbl.status = '0'
    bet_tbl.bet_Date ='2013-07-02'
    Group by bet_number
) T1
JOIN recover_tbl T2
ON T1.bet_number = T2.recover_number
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want bet_tbl.bet_Number = '11', you are missing it in the where

```
select 
  `bet_Number`, 
  SUM(bet_tbl.`Amount`) - SUM(recover_tbl.`Amount`) AS 'AMOUNT'
from bet_tbl, recover_tbl
WHERE bet_tbl.status= recover_tbl.status
  AND bet_tbl.`bet_Date`=recover_tbl.`recover_Date` 
  AND bet_tbl.status = '0'
  AND bet_tbl.`bet_Date`='2013-07-02'
  and bet_tbl.bet_Number = '11'
GROUP BY bet_tbl.`bet_Number`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding `Distinct` clause in front of `bet_Number` or `Max(bet_number)`